# Запятая на грани глаголов "стоял" и "думал"

Tags: пунктуация

Я замер, я стоял думал о случившемся, о пережитом потрясении.

Нужна ли запятая между глаголами "стоял" и "думал", или "думал" относится уже к обстоятельству (с какой целью?)?

Comment: _Владимир: Нужна ли запятая между глаголами "стоял" и "думал"..._ === А как Вы произносите это предложение: с паузой после "стоял" или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая между такими глаголами обычно не ставится.

Сказуемое представлено лексически ограниченным сочетанием двух спрягаемых форм глаголов, из которых один означает движение или пребывание в состоянии, положение в пространстве: *сидеть, стоять, идти, бежать, ходить, лежать* (или мотивированные ими); другой глагол лексически свободен: *сидит шьет, стоит дожидается, успокаивают приходят, лежит охает, ворчит ходит, зайду проведаю, спите ложитесь, посидим отдохнем, сижу смотрю телевизор, он мне здесь мешает стоит, идет шатается; Поедем съездим за дровишками (Шукш.); Секретари сидели — глаза поднять не смели* (Абр.).[Сказуемое](https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/skazuemoe-96573.html)